# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I realise that this error happens when you attempt to do some sort of network request on the UI thread, but as you can see in the code below I am actually calling the Http Get in an AsyncTask:

```
public class LeftPaneFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageView _profileImage;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(wj.tweetTab.R.layout.left_pane, container);

        _profileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        setUpProfileInfo(view);

        return view;
    }

    private void setUpProfileInfo(View view) {          
        new SetUpUserInfo().doInBackground();
    }

    private class SetUpUserInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable> {

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(_model.UserInfo.ProfileImageUrl);

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);        
                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {               
                Log.e("setUpUserInfo.doInBackground", e.getMessage());
            }

            return Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, "src");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            _profileImage.setImageDrawable(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see any obvious problems here? Also can the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception be thrown for any other reason than doing a http request in the main thread?

I am a newcomer to Android, only been working with it a few days.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> but as you can see in the code below I am actually calling the Http
>   Get in an AsyncTask

You're not, actually. You need to call `execute()` instead of calling `doInBackground()` directly, otherwise you're not using any of the plumbing provided by the `AsyncTask`, and you're just calling the method directly in the UI thread.

Comment: I have tripped over this several times, and have gotten close to doing it several more times with threads (Start vs. run). Why is `doInBackground()` even available when it's this useless?

Comment: Uh... what do you mean "available"? First of all, it's `protected`, which means you're not supposed to be calling it from a class outside of the AsyncTask. Unfortunately, many people just declare the AsyncTasks inline so they can (and do) call `doInBackground()`. `execute()` however, *is* `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Android SDK version is to high (version >= 3.0).

Try to add code

import android.os.StrictMode;

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()   
        .detectDiskReads()   
        .detectDiskWrites()   
        .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems   
        .penaltyLog()   
        .build());
```

in `onCreateView()` function;

Comment: This is bad practice. They added this mode so people would not code network related stuff on the UI Thread. It is a Workaround only 1 step higher than a hack. Code correctly is the better solution.