# android asynctask NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm trying to write a server/client app in android using sockets and i handle the client socket in `AsyncTask` (server is not android, just ordinary java).I get the exception when I'm trying to read from the server.I found out that when I delete `android:targetSdkVersion="16"` from android manifest the exception goes away and I can read from the server.

I don't understand why is that? could anyone help me clarify this? I also have problems understanding how the asynctask method `doInBackground` and my own methods relate. Does `conhandler.execute()` run `doInBackground()`  and then just waits until I call the other methods? thanks for help.

```
public class ConnectionHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

public static String serverip = "10.0.2.2";
public static int serverport = 5000;
Socket s;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        s = new Socket(serverip, serverport);
        Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Created Socket");
    }...
    if (s.isConnected()) {
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Socket created, Streams assigned");

    } ....
 }

public void writeToStream(String message) {
 try {
     if (s.isConnected()){
        out.println(message);
    } else {
        Log.i("AsynkTask", "writeToStream : Cannot write to stream, Socket is closed");
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("AsynkTask", "writeToStream : Writing failed");
   }  
 }

 public String readFromStream() {
try {
    if (s.isConnected()) {
        Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Reading message");
        String ret=in.readLine();
        Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : read "+ret);
        return ret;
    } else {
        Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Cannot Read, Socket is closed");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Reading failed"+e.getClass());
}
return null;
}
}
```

this is my main activity

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private EditText view_email;
private EditText view_password;
TextView result;
ConnectionHandler conhandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    conhandler = new ConnectionHandler();
    conhandler.execute();       
    }


public void register(View view) {
     view_email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    view_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    String email=view_email.getText().toString();
    String password=view_password.getText().toString();
    conhandler.writeToStream("register");
    conhandler.writeToStream(email);
    conhandler.writeToStream(password);
    String res=conhandler.readFromStream(); //here's the exception
    result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    result.setText(res);
 }
 }
```

Comment: could you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: register() function is called from where?

Comment: You need to do you network calls in doInBackground. Your methods writeToStream and readFromStream are executed on the UI thread, not on the AsyncTask thread. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: This seems to be relevant:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408046/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-in-asynctask (tl;dr don't doInBackground() from your thread, call its `.execute()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

There are two Solution of this Problem.

1) Don't write network call in Main UIThread, Use Async Task for that.

2) Write below code into your MainActivity file after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

And below import statement into your java file.

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

Comment: the conhandler i'm calling the method on is an asynctask

Answer (score -2):

> ```
>  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> ```

this eror comes With **HoneyComb(3.0 or Later).**

**you can not perform a networking operation on its main thread as documentation says.** to getting ride of this you must use handler or asynctask. AFAIK There is no another way to do it.

you can See this for More Details [WHY ICS Crashes your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Try Using Below Code Snippet

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        //do your Code Here    
    }
}.start();
```